# what does "had a father turn to him" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> One of our workers had a father turn to him.

From what I learned, the structure "have somebody do something" is a request or command to ask people to do something for you. So, at first, I thought that it was the worker who asked the father for help. While carefully considering the context of the sentence, I think this sentence is more likely to say that the father turns to the worker for help.

So, which one is true?

I couldn't give the original text of my question, due to the restrictions on the Internet in my country. But the article comes from National Geographic and the title is *Too Young To Wed*. My question is in the penultimate paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither.

Having googled and found the article in question, the father is explaining to the worker why he will not do what the worker wants him to do. i.e. the worker wants fathers to stop marrying their young daughters to old men.

The father is saying that if he doesn't marry his daughter when she is young then she might be raped and then he won't be able to marry her at all. He is asking the worker a rhetorical question: will you protect her? to which the answer is obviously no--the worker won't be there. So the father will continue to marry his daughters off young. [Not saying I agree with it, simply explaining what is being said.]

Comment: So he didn't approach the worker for help, but he did approach him/her to say something - not at the worker's request.

Answer (score 3):

*Have somebody do something* can (especially in American English) mean *ask or order them* to do it. However, it can also mean *have the experience of somebody doing something.*

> I've had people come up to me in the street and ask...

It's most likely that your sentence means that a father approached the worker (for help?).

Comment: I had a dog pee on my leg once, and I promise you I did not ask or or order it to do that.